# How to filter a list based on an input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf-2

I have a JSF 2.0 application with a basic search bar with a list of contacts that is updated on `keyup` so that only the values that match the text in the search bar are displayed.

```
<h:panelGroup id="contacts_tab_contacts_list">
    <h:form id="search_bar_form">
        <h:panelGroup id="contacts_tab_search_bar">
            <h:inputText id="search_bar_text"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
    <c:forEach items="#{currentDevice.contacts}" var="contact">
        <li>
            <h:panelGroup id="contact_#{contact.phoneNumber}">
                <h:outputText value="#{contact.phoneNumber}" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </li>
    </c:forEach>
</h:panelGroup>
```

I would like it to be fast so I want to implement it with JavaScript/jQuery. 
I'm new to the JavaScript/jQuery world, so I could use a little help with this.
How could I do this?

Comment: have a look at this : http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: Thanks @JohnP, I'm looking to see if I can figure out how to implement this on my project (Since autocomplete is a nice feature, but it's not exactly what I need)

Comment: could you be more specific ? when you say you want a client side solution , does that mean that data (contacts) are already downloaded in the page and you just need to regex search them , or do you mean using ajax to do the trick ?

Comment: As you said, the list will be downloaded to the client and be filtered with the searchbar using Ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the view as follows (added `<ul>`, used `<ui:repeat>` instead of `<c:forEach>`, removed some unnecessary `<h:panelGroup>`s to minimize noise, the `<h:form>` is also not necessary since there's nothing which needs to be submitted to the server side)

```
<input id="search" />
<ul id="contacts">
    <ui:repeat value="#{currentDevice.contacts}" var="contact">
        <li>#{contact.phoneNumber}</li>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

And use this script to filter the list:

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var $search = $(this).val();
    $('#contacts li').each(function() {
        var $li = $(this);
        if ($li.text().indexOf($search) > -1) {
            $li.show();
        } else {
            $li.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

why to re invent the wheel [RichFaces already provide this](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/filteringFeature.jsf)

Comment: Doesn't RichFaces use a server-side solution?

Comment: Yes it is. then how about [this jquery plugin](http://gregweber.info/projects/uitablefilter